# How to delete text from EditText but EditText editable false

Tags: android, android-edittext

My requirement is that users can not add text in `EditText` after 25 char but can delete char from `EditText`.

Here is my code:

```
groupName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.groupName);
groupName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d("TEXTHellow",start+" "+before+" "+count);
        if (groupName.length() > 24) {
            groupName.setFocusable(false);
            groupName.setClickable(false);
            groupName.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            groupName.setLongClickable(false);
            groupName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        }
        int remChar=25-count;
        numChar.setText(remChar+"");
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: cant you use android:maxLength="25" !!!

Comment: android:maxLength = "25"  in layout XML

Answer (score 3):

If you want to limit the number of char in the `EditText` to 25:

```
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(25);
groupName.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use  **substring()** method

```
String numChar= EditText.getText().toString();
if (numChar.length() > 24) {
numChar= str.substring ( 0, numChar.length() - 1 );// here am delete one last letter
EditText.setText ( numChar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not specify the maximum character accepted by the  `edittext` would be only 25,

This would reduces the hustle of unnecessary coding which is not required.

If i understand your question right this would be a lot easier. `android:maxLength="25"`

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:maxLines="1" />
```

lets say that your text in the EditText changes, in other words you are not sure what would be the maximum length of the editText, you can use following code. Kindly check this [setFilters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters%28android.text.InputFilter[]%29)

```
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TestLayoutActivity_editText);
    InputFilter[] inputFilter = {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(editText.getText().toString().length())};
    editText.setFilters(inputFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 groupName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (groupName.getText().toString().length() >= 24) {
                    groupName.setError("Max 24 characters");
                    valid_num = null;
                }else {
                    valid_num = groupName.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add maxLength attribute in xml :

```
android:maxLength="25"
```

and in OnTextChangeListener :

```
yourEditText.setText("Characters remaining : "+Integer.toString(25-(s.length())));
```